# Why does this not contradict Cauchy's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C}\ : 1<|z|<3\}$, and put $f(z)=1/z$. Let $\alpha:[0,1] \rightarrow 2\exp(2i\pi t)$. Then $\int_\alpha f \, dz=2\pi i$. But surely Cauchy's theorem says that this integral is $0,$ since $f$ is analytic in $D$?

Comment: Or is it because this domain is not simply connected, which would make sense

Comment: Yes, it's exactly because the domain is not simply connected. You might try to solve this by changing $D$ to $\{|z| < 3\}$ instead, but then $f$ is no longer analytic.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem holds when the winding number of the contour about any point in the complement of the domain is zero. There are plenty of points in the complement here about  which the curve has nonzero winding number.

Comment: Why do you say "surely"? Examine the hypotheses of this theorem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that $\alpha$ is *not* null-homotopic in $D$.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia's account of Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) says:

> [L]et $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb C$ which is simply connected, let $f:U\to\mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function, and let $\gamma$ be a rectifiable path in $U$ whose start point is equal to its end point. Then $$\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0. $$

The open set that you describe is not simply connected (although it is connected), so Cauchy's theorem is not applicable.